# Sharing a connection pool among two connection strings

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Identity out-of-the-box with an ASP.NET MVC application (I didn't have time to implement my own custom storage).

I'm also using Entity Framework in the same application.

So I ended up with two connection strings, both pointing to the same database (same server, same database, same username and password).

I'd like to leverage the connection pool feature, but I read that ASP.NET creates a connection pool for each connection string.

My question is - can I share" the connection pool among these two connection strings?

Comment: Why do you need this?  What is the problem with having two connection pools?

Comment: same database, two connection strings in single application? Connection pool is for db not for connection strings. can you clear the context please.

Comment: Why don't you use the same connection string if the DB is the same?